# Build MEF plugins without RebuildAll

Tags: wpf, plugins, visual-studio-2015, build, mef

I have MEF-modules (assemblies) in same solution as Main WPF Application. Modules reference Main, so they can implement IModule used by MEF.

Since MainApp does not reference IModule implementations, they are only build on Clean + RebuildAll - not normal Build (F5). And I would like it to.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Can't you put your MEF-modules into separate project?

Comment: VS2015 menu: Build -> "Configuration Manager...". There are check boxes for Build for each project. Are those checked?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Solution Explorer and right click your MainApp project. Select "Build Dependencies" and then "Project Dependencies". Then check all the projects that contain `IModule` implementations.

This tells Visual Studio to build these projects before building your MainApp project (if any modifications have been made to these projects).